# Enveloping/Decrypting a large PKCS#7 (.p7m) byte array in C#

Tags: c#, .net, security, encryption, cryptography

I am using .net framework 4.5 and .net System.Security.Cryptography library to decrypt a large .p7m file and the file size is around 70mb. the .p7m file have been transformed to byte array and I would like to use the EnvelopedCms class to decode the .p7m byte array. However, it take a long execution time (around 3xx seconds) when performing envelopedCms.Decode(p7mByteArray)

```
byte[] p7mByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(ATTACHMENT_PATH);
EnvelopedCms envelopedCms = new EnvelopedCms();
envelopedCms.Decode(p7mByteArray);
```

1. How can I increase the performance of envelopedCms.Decode() if it is a large byte array?
2. Does envelopedCms.Decode() support streaming on byte array in .net framework 4.5?
3. Any other alternative solutions to decode the enveloped byte array with faster performance speed?

Thanks.

Comment: This is why encryption of large data is done using symmetric cryptography, and asymmetric public-private key crypto is used only for protecting the symmetric key and a signature / message authentication code.

Comment: @BenVoigt CMS already performs hybrid encryption. anguspcw, it would be a good idea to post the first bytes of the CMS message in bytes so we can retrieve the used algorithms from the header. Also: execution speed also depends on the computer it is used on, please post specs. And finally: also test without virusscanner.

Comment: Bouncy Castle (for C#) contains a streaming API (which seems to have been optimized in 2007 according to the release notes).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have tried the bouncy castle for C#, it has a better performance compared with .net cryptography library (few seconds). However, some reasons that my certificate must marked as non-exportable, the private key retrieved from .net X509Store cannot transform to bouncy castle key object so that I cannot use bouncy castle for encryption/decryption.

Comment: Even if BC for C# is not a Cryptographic Service Provider as for the Java release, you could still rewrite the (Open Source) library to use the private key operation defined within the .NET framework. Still, anything near 300 seconds for 70 MB is *excessive*. How long does it take to perform on a very small file (just to see what takes more resources: the private key operation or processing the bytes themselves)?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes the long execution time that occurred when the bytes is processing in the CryptMsgUpdate of Crypt32.dll, not the processing of decryption part.